# What does "strident note" mean?

Tags: idioms

so I'm translating an RPG book from English to Brazilian Portuguese and stumbled upon (for the first time) with the expression "strident note". I'm not familiar with it, and although I can sort of grasp the overall idea of the excerpt where it appears, I wanted to have a better understanding of its meaning, but my attempts to google it returned no results with its meaning, just examples of usage.

Can anyone help me? Here's the excerpt:

> "Ana's ultimate goal is to persuade her husband to use his authority
>   to have the cigani identified as an undesirable pagan influence on
>   [...]. Unfortunately, Father Filopovic is a more tolerant man than she
>   had anticipated, and a **strident note** has entered her calls to
>   eject the cigani."

Comment: This is just two words in a row, they should be looked up individually in a dictionary.

Comment: they happen enough together to give me a feeling there's a figurative meaning that ppl unfamiliar with it wouldn't grasp, that's why I'm asking...

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but after no definition for the collocation is found, then that concept can be dismissed and the individual words can be looked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal strident sound is one that is "loud, unpleasant, and rough"; figuratively the term can be used about something expressed in forceful language that does not try to avoid upsetting other people. Ana's efforts to have the cigani identified as a pagan influence (etc) were not as successful as she had hoped, so she used forceful, possibly impolite, language in calling for their ejection.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strident

Comment: thank you, I can understand and see that!